# How to subscribe to change in observableArray's item

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, observable

I have prepared a basic knockout.js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/utm02ohk/2/

For completeness I will repeat parts of the code here:

In my View I've got foreach loop which iterates over an observableArray of items:

```
        <div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
         <div class="switchBox">
          <div class="switchName"><strong data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + name()"></strong></div>
           <label class="Switch">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: state">
           </label>
         </div>
       </div>
```

It basically iterates over elements I have in my availableItems array:

```
self.availableItems([
new Item(1, "item1", state1, self.onItemStateChange),
new Item(2, "item2", state2, self.onItemStateChange),
new Item(3, "item3", state3, self.onItemStateChange)
]);
```

as you can see, I also have a function in which i initialize each of those items with observables:

```
function Item(id, name, state, onChange) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.state = ko.observable(state);

  self.state.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    onChange(self, newValue);
  });
}
```

Each of the items in an array has state variables (state1, state2, state3), which are boolean and they control which chekbox is checked and which one is not. They are (for the sake of this example) set at the beggining of ViewModel:

```
var state1 = true;
var state2 = false;
var state3 = false;
```

In reality state1, state2 and state3 are mapped from server. What I want to achieve, is after I initialize my items with starting state values, I want them to be subscribed on every change of state1, state2 and state3, so that checkbox is checked or not checked, depending on the recieved value from the server.

Currently, they are not being changed after the first initialization. I need to do this with as least changes to existing code approach as possible, since it affects a lot of other stuff in the original code.

Is this possible to do, and if yes, can someone please explain how to code this in knockout.js?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right I think this will solve your problem with very little change to your existing code:
https://jsfiddle.net/sr3wy17t/

```js
function Item(id, name, state, onChange) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.state = ko.observable(state);

  self.state.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    onChange(self, newValue);
  });
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  var state1 = true;
  var state2 = false;
  var state3 = false;

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.activeItemss = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.availableItems().filter(function(item) {
      return item.state();
    });
  });

  self.onItemStateChange = function(item, newValue) {
    console.log("State change event: " + item.name() + " (" + newValue + ")");
  };


  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems([
      new Item(1, "item1", state1, self.onItemStateChange),
      new Item(2, "item2", state2, self.onItemStateChange),
      new Item(3, "item3", state3, self.onItemStateChange)
    ]);
    setInterval(() => {
      var itemNoThatChanged = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      var newState = Math.random() > 0.5;
      self.availableItems()[itemNoThatChanged].state(newState)
    }, 1000)
  };
}


var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <div class="switchBox">
    <div class="switchName"><strong data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + name()"></strong></div>
    <label class="Switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: state">
                  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

(In the setInterval function you should have an ajax call to get the updatedvalues)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will this work if a state is a part of another ViewModel?
Can I use pureComputed for activeItems instead of computed?

Comment: I think so to both questions - if you have a problem then make a fiddle and post it here

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, it is not exactly what I meant. I want to code it so that only change to state1, state2 or state3 causes the checkbox to corespond to the new state.
You are directly changing item in the array, which is not the situation I have once I receive response from server. Can you please help with this?